# Liquibase error finding parent directory when using valueClobFile attribute

Tags: blob, filepath, liquibase, clob

I am currently using `liquibase` to carry out an update to an existing table in a `sql` database. I have included the `xml` script which I have written below.

The problem occurs when trying to use the `valueClobFile` attribute. I am trying to specify a file location in another parent directory, However the `liquibase` script does not like redirecting more than one parent directory up. For example in the code below the file path of `valueClobFile="../customer-data/CustomerDesc.json"` works perfectly.

However when trying to navigate more than one parent directory up, the file path seems to fail.
 **e.g.**
`valueClobFile="../../raw-data/customer-data/CustomerDesc.json"`

```
  <update tableName="CUSTOMER_LIST">
        <column name="RAW_DETAILS" valueClobFile="../customer-data/CustomerDesc.json">
        <where>schema_name = 'engines'</where>
  </update>
```

Is there an existing bug in the code that doesn't let you reference a file path which is located more than 2 parent directories up?